# Prototype API not work in WSO2 API manger 1.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created a prototype API in WSO2 API manager 1.9. But i am  getting following error while accessing the API

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<am:code>0</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>
Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator
</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

What is the reason ,Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't you see any errors in API Manager logs?

Comment: Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator --getting this log in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue in APIM 1.9.0 when JWT is enabled. Please refer this jira [1] to find out the work around.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3913

Thanks!